# Bash parameter expanstion to remove tabs

Tags: bash

I've got such a line in script:

```
TATVAR=$(echo $PARAMVAR|sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//')
```

I'd like to shrink this to not to execute additional program (sed), shellcheck suggested to me that i should use:

```
${variable//search/replace}
```

I've tried many regexps but seems it doesn't work. Does anyone have idea how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `"${PARAMVAR//$'\t'/}"`, but note that this is a bash feature, so other shells might not support it. That means start your script with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh` (and *do not* run it with `sh scriptname`).

```
$ PARAMVAR=$'space: tab:\tlinefeed:\nend'
$ echo "$PARAMVAR"
space: tab: linefeed:
end
$ echo "${PARAMVAR//$'\t'/}"
space: tab:linefeed:
end
```

For comparison, using `[[:blank:]]` will get rid of spaces as well:

```
$ echo "${PARAMVAR//[[:blank:]]/}"
space:tab:linefeed:
end
```

And you should always wrap variable references in double-quotes, or else all whitespace gets treated as word breaks (and `echo` will then turn them into spaces):

```
$ echo $PARAMVAR
space: tab: linefeed: end
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation but this seem to not to work in my particular example. I have some nagios check which returns proper value when i use [[:blank:]] parameter, but using your example returns invalid value.
I was searching for good reference manual for ${var//search/replace} but i haven't found anything worth to see. Have you got maybe link for some good documation of this functionality of bash? Official Bash Reference Manual didn't help.

Comment: @MateuszPacek It sounds like there's something other than tabs in the string (sequences of spaces?) that `[[:blank:]]` is matching but `$'\t'` isn't. Try examining the string with `echo "$PARAMVAR" | LC_ALL=C cat -vet` -- that should show tabs as "^I", and spaces just as spaces. As for documentation, you have to look at the "3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion" and "3.5.8.1 Pattern Matching" sections; also, check [BashFAQ #100: How do I do string manipulations in bash?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100#Substituting_part_of_a_string).

Comment: Ok Gordon, I've got raw output of the command ($ means tab in my case):  
**ONLINE SLAVE $**
The sed output is:  
**ONLINE SLAVE$**

How to get rid of this tab at the end? 
**ONLINE SLAVE**
The output using your advice:

Comment: @MateuszPacek In the output from `cat -vet`, $ means linefeed, and that's added by `echo` so you should ignore it. from the output, that's not a tab at all, it's just a space. But if you do a global removal of blanks (`//[[:blank:]]/`), it should be removing the space in the middle as well (i.e. "ONLINESLAVE"), so I'm really confused what's going on here.

Answer (score 0):

I've just managed this by:

```
TATVAR="${PARAMVAR//[[:blank:]]/}"
```

I'd be glad if someone can confirm that it's correct.